# Change a row of cells to be a certain formula

Tags: excel

I have this row of data with actual numbers.

For a specific reason ... I need to update the same row of cells to do the following:

`=(number from cell same)*$J$5`

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Range("$J$5").Copy
Range("B9:Z9").PasteSpecial Operation:=xlMultiply
```

or, if you need a formula that depends on J5:

```
For Each c In Range("A10:Z10")
    c.Formula = "=$J$5*" & c.Value
Next c
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid problems of circular references, just use a copy of the source row.